# Geometry Nodes: Affect only the fillet of a fillet curve, such as averaging the Z position

Tags: geometry-nodes

First, the pseudo-code of what I am attempting to do. This is what I'd be doing if it was just in Edit Mode:

1. Have some edges. Some are chained, some are single edges
2. Bevel the vertices between edges
3. Select those beveled edges
4. Switch the pivot point to Individual Origins
5. Scale Z 0

Now to do it in Geometry Nodes! So far I've converted to curve, filleted the curve, deleted the final endpoint of each curve  (to prevent Modulo skips) and deleted rogue verts (left over from singular edge chains.) Now I want to average the Z position of the 2 vertices that make up each fillet. Any ideas? I can't seem to crack the Geometry nodes equivalent of Scale by Individual Origins for edges.
[image]

Comment: This is, say, to generate horizontal hairpins in a road?

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer" so that this question will not continue to be displayed as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some development of this approach?

- After conversion to Curve, set up a second branch, in which the curve is filleted to near-0
- Transfer the Z-position from that branch to the fully-filleted curve, by index.

[image]

That would make the difference shown below:

[image]

If this looks promising, further work could be done on handle-lengths, etc. for more control.

Answer (score 1):

If I have not completely misunderstood this task, you are looking for this solution:

[image]

Here I subdivide the curve with `Subdivide Curve` and then filter out the vertices created by the node `Fillet Curve`.

[image]